# how to show single post in a custom template

Tags: posts, categories, page-template

hi i used the below code to list out the posts in a particular category.

```
<div class="wrapred">
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : 

                        ?>
                    <?php query_posts('category_name=services&showposts=5'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


         <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

             <div class="popthumb"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a><?php echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;'; the_title(); ?></h2>

 </div>

 <div class="popcontent">

  <?php the_excerpt();?>
    </div>

                    </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

it works fine. but now when i click on the excerpt read more link the post shows in a unordered template. i need to show them as like the subpages are showing. i have a subpage template file. how can i use that file for displaying single posts??

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly, but wanted to point out that `query_posts()` is kind of frowned upon and you should probably use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

Comment: I think he is asking that he wants to show the output of this(post from the category_name) above code to his custom template. I mean when he clicks the link he should be seeing the post in his custom template.

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Is your code from a particular template file, or is it a custom page template? Does the single-post view for the queried posts need to be different from the default single-post view, or can they be the same? If they need to be different, how do you differentiate the posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most templates, the file `single.php` is used to display a single post. So you can use the code from the subpage template file in `single.php` to style a single post.

Comment: thank you sir... one more doubt.. how can i show the featured image in the template also?now it shows only the content. i use the_content() for that.

Comment: You can do that using the `the_post_thumbnail` function, see the wordpress codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) on how to use it. Also; Google is your friend with these kind of questions. There is a lot of information out there!

Comment: i know that function sir.. it shows thumbnail images. i want the orginal size image in the page. not the thumbnail.

Comment: Ah OK. Then you can use `wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);`, so `wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'full');`